# MySQL PHP query not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

The following code doesn't seem to be working correctly, when I put just 1 thing in WHERE it works fine so maybe I cant do multiple items in here?

The code snippet is

```
$query_view_users = "SELECT id, type, name, username, email FROM admin_users WHERE id, type, name, username, email LIKE '$search'";
```

Thank you so much for your help.  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's a multi-condition `WHERE` clause. use `OR` or `AND` which ever satifies your needs.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ....
WHERE id   LIKE '$search' OR 
      type LIKE '$search' OR 
      name LIKE '$search' OR 
      username LIKE '$search' OR 
      email    LIKE '$search'
```

Comment: OR or AND? Looks like he meant AND. +1'ed

Comment: @janenz00 yeah, i added both. it depends on what he needs :D

Answer (score 0):

your sql would have to be

```
$query_view_users = "SELECT * FROM admin_users WHERE id OR type OR name OR username OR email LIKE '$search'";
```